# Pre selected in HTML based on context in django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I need to display a select input field with fixed option

```
<select multiple>
                        <option > area</option>
                        <option > city</option>
                        <option > project</option>
                        <option > address</option>
                        <option > item3</option>
                        <option > item4</option>
                        <option > anotheritem</option>
                        <option > otheritem</option>
                        <option > lastitem</option>
                        <option > itemrandom</option>
</select>
```

And I am passing a list in the context which will have item as (area, address, city) one or more or all.
I want the option to be **pre-selected**  if any of the value of the options is present in the passed context list.

The html page will be rendered from a django view. Using a form is not preferable.

Comment: Are you passing the options as well from backend or they are hardcoded and only selected values will be passed in context?

Comment: They are hardcoded.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="area" {% if "area" in selected_values %} selected {% endif %}> area</option>
  <option value="city" {% if "city" in selected_values %} selected {% endif %}> city</option>
  <option value="project" {% if "project" in selected_values %} selected {% endif %}> project</option>
  <option value="address" {% if "address" in selected_values %} selected {% endif %}> address</option>
  <option value="item3" {% if "item3" in selected_values %} selected {% endif %}> item3</option>
  <option value="item4" {% if "item4" in selected_values %} selected {% endif %}> item4</option>
  <option value="anotheritem" {% if "anotheritem" in selected_values %} selected {% endif %}> anotheritem</option>
  <option value="otheritem" {% if "otheritem" in selected_values %} selected {% endif %}> otheritem</option>
  <option value="lastitem" {% if "lastitem" in selected_values %} selected {% endif %}> lastitem</option>
  <option value="itemrandom" {% if "itemrandom" in selected_values %} selected {% endif %}> itemrandom</option>
</select>
```

The above snippet must do the job, it would be better if you pass the list of all options also from the backend.
In that case below snippet would do the job;

```
<select multiple>
  {% for option in options %}
  <option value="{{option}}" {% if option in selected_values %} selected {% endif %}> {{option}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: ```{% if "area" in selected_values %}```  selected_values will be a list so the code won't work as in django template we can't check for a value in a list, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: selected_values will be the list of the values that are already selected for example;
selected_values = ["area", "itemrandom", "city", "project"]